# SQL Server query on xml datatype for the value present in the tag

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server database with a table `FormTable` that has a column `DataXML` in xml format.

Data in that XML column looks like:

```
<Form>
  <Section name="metric1">
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="Length of the box.">
      <Value>50</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <PickList title="Is the shape square?">
      <Option selected="true">Yes</Option>
      <Option>No</Option>
      <Option>No standard shape</Option>
    </PickList>
  </Section>
</Form>
```

The XML contains many more `InputNumber` and `PickList` tags. I have written this query to fetch the required data. It returns:

- category -- row number -- title
- metric1 --   1 --     Length of the box
- metric1 --   2 --     Is the shape square?

```
SELECT 
    tbl.FormId,
    category = c.value(''../../@name'', ''VARCHAR(max)''),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 1)) as RowNumber,
    c.value(''../@title'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [title]
FROM 
    FormTable AS tbl
CROSS APPLY 
    tbl.DataXML.nodes(''/Form[1]/Section/*[local-name() = ("PickList", "InputNumber"")]/*[local-name() = ("Value", "Option")]'') AS t(c)
WHERE
    Formid = '10';
```

Now I want to return one more column called value and the result should look be:

- category -- row number -- title        --   value
- metric1 --   1 --     Length of the box --   50
- metric1 --   2 --     Is the shape square?  -- Yes

How to fetch the value column?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the value (inner text) of the current element just use `c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') as [value]`, for example:

```sql
create table FormTable (
  FormID int not null,
  DataXML xml
);

insert FormTable (FormID, DataXML) values
(10, N'<Form>
  <Section name="metric1">
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="Length of the box.">
      <Value>50</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <PickList title="Is the shape square?">
      <Option selected="true">Yes</Option>
      <Option>No</Option>
      <Option>No standard shape</Option>
    </PickList>
  </Section>
</Form>');

SELECT 
    tbl.FormId,
    category = c.value('../../@name', 'VARCHAR(max)'),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t.c) as RowNumber,
    c.value('../@title',  'VARCHAR(max)') AS [title],
    c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') as [value]
FROM 
    FormTable AS tbl
CROSS APPLY 
    tbl.DataXML.nodes('/Form[1]/Section/*[local-name() = ("PickList", "InputNumber")]/*[local-name() = ("Value", "Option")]') AS t(c)
WHERE
    FormID = 10;
```

Which yields the result:

```
FormId  category  RowNumber  title                 value
10      metric1   1          Length of the box.    50
10      metric1   2          Is the shape square?  Yes
10      metric1   3          Is the shape square?  No
10      metric1   4          Is the shape square?  No standard shape
```

Comment: From the picklist, I want only selected value i.e 10 ,metric1, 2 ,Is the shape square?,  Yes. I dont want other rows i.e row number 3 and 4